# How to create dynamic Keyframe rules in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I've been trying for the last few weeks to execute my idea in various ways (I'm new to Javascript) and have tried many approaches, this being the closest to coming to fruition.

**My Target**

My aim is to create 100 moving dots (each representing a percentage) that animate to their respective positions, like a progress bar of sorts but in a circle format. As the percentage goes higher, the corresponding dots have a larger radius. My current code is: [Full Code](https://jsbin.com/jimohah/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
var hundredPointsArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    hundredPointsArray += '<div class="hundredPoints"></div>';
}

var containerHundredPoints = document.querySelector(".conHundredPoints");
containerHundredPoints.innerHTML = hundredPointsArray;

for (var i = 0; i < hundredPointsArray.length; i++){
    var sheet = document.createElement('style')
    var circle = document.querySelectorAll(".hundredPoints");

    sheet.textContent = "@-webkit-keyframes testA {"
        + "0% {transform:translate(495px, 495px) rotate(45deg) translate("+ -i*4 +"px," 
        + -i*4 +"px);"
        + "background-color:white; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;}"
        + "100% {transform:translate(495px, 495px) rotate(405deg) translate("+ -i*4 
        + "px, "+ -i*4 +"px);"
        + "background-color:black; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #980;}";

    circle[i].appendChild(sheet);
}
```

I've created an array (20 Divs for just testing) and, created and assigned a keyframe to each one.

**The Problem** is that all dots are assigned the last keyframe the loop makes. I've tried making an array for the stylesheets first and assigned the `ith` Keyframe to the `ith` Div with no luck.

E.g.: The first dot will have an orbiting radius of 4 pixels, the second 8 pixels, the tenth will have 40 pixels etc... whatever units and sizes I decide later on, this is just for an example of the incremental idea I have.

Essentially, without having to make 100 unique Divs with one adjusted parameter, I wish to make a loop that will create a unique Keyframe animation quickly and simply, and assigned that to it's respective Div.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated and I'm happy to fill in any missing details that any helpers would like to know.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Wave effect: I'd like there to be a minor delay for the next dot down the array to move and the reverse to happen when the animation reverses, i.e. the first dot to move first and the last dot to move last, but also when reversing to their original positions the last dot (meaning the last dot to reach it's current) moves back first and the first dot moves back last. I attempted to add a delay into the Div creating array however this only delayed the start and did not repeat or reverse. I suspect it can be done with controlling the keyframe timing but that would be trial and error for me.

Comment: 3. Finally, colour control. I'm still playing around with this one and I'm to try and have the fun of solving it myself before asking, and it may help me learn faster :) my colour coordination is red (bad), green (average) and gold (good) which can currently be seen in the link below [link](https://jsbin.com/vijuqoy/edit?html,css,js,output) . Assuming a constant, gradual gradient change through the three colours, I'd like each point to go through the colour states then stop at it's own expected colour. Also, if it's in between red and green, the dot is appropriately between the colours too.

Comment: 2 Limiting variable. I've called this 'actualPercent'. The goal is to display fancy looking progress bar between 0%-100% (starting at the top and going clockwise). Each point represents a percent and moves to their respective position along their radius (with the thin grey circles representing 25%, 50% and 75%, smallest to largest). If i wanted to display that someone had completed 40% of something, then I'd want only the first 40 points to move to their respective positions while the others remain dormant (effectively staying at 0%). [link](https://jsbin.com/vijuqoy/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: 3 update: although previously stated would be ideal, if the points were to not have gradual colour differences and were all pure red, green and gold in their respective thresholds (e.g.under 30 is red and above 70 gold), that would simplify my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think this code would be an aproach of what you need, I'm not sure but if you want more help you can share a picture of what you really want to do (final result).

Remove this rule `-webkit-animation-name: 'testA';`

```
.hundredPoints{
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
    position:absolute;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-radius:100%;
}
```

Assign a specific class to each point `point-(ith)`.

```
var hundredPointsArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    hundredPointsArray += '<div class="hundredPoints point-' + i + '"></div>';
}

var containerHundredPoints = document.querySelector(".conHundredPoints");
containerHundredPoints.innerHTML = hundredPointsArray;
```

Create a new animation keyframe for each specific point,
then assign it to each specific class crated before.

```
for (var i = 0; i < hundredPointsArray.length; i++){
var sheet = document.createElement('style')
var circle = document.querySelectorAll(".hundredPoints");
sheet.textContent = ""+
    ".hundredPoints.point-" + i + " {" +
        "-webkit-animation-name: 'animPoint-" + i + "';" +
    "}" +

    "@-webkit-keyframes animPoint-" + i + " {" +
        "0% { transform:translate(495px, 495px)" +
             "rotate(45deg) translate(" + (-i * 4) + "px," + (-i * 4) + "px);" +
             "background-color:white;" +
             "box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;" +
        "}" +

        "100% { transform:translate(495px, 495px)" +
               "rotate(405deg)" +
               "translate(" + (-i * 4) + "px," + (-i * 4) + "px);" +
               "background-color:black;" +
               "box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #980;" +
        "}";
    "}";

    circle[i].appendChild(sheet);
}
```

Here is the [complete code](https://jsbin.com/ruqetihugu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: That is excellent! Thank you so much, I sincerely appreciate your help with this one, honestly. I did try assigning a unique class to my Divs to no avail, so I'm glad to see that could have actually worked in the end.Here is the completed code so far (with your amendments): [link](https://jsbin.com/vijuqoy/edit?html,css,js,output) . The final idea incorporates three other features: 1. a wave effect when the dots move, 2. a limit variable (e.g. 40, so only the first 40 dots move and others remain stationary), and 3, colour control. I'll expand in a comment on my question page if you'd like?

Comment: You're welcome! The result in your link in very impressive, congrats! Yes, you can expand your question with a comment :).

Comment: Thank you, I only started Javascript a month or two ago and it's hit and miss at most times. I know I've still got a lot to learn and I'll happily take all the time I need to do it :) and I'm aware I'm "running before I can walk" with this small project/idea but I've a clear idea in mind I'd like to reach. Thanks again for all your time and effort, I can't thank you enough. And apologies for any poor English, I'm trying to describe in as much detail as i can in the comments with limited character space, please ask if something doesn't seem clearly put. Kind regards.